# python: stdout PIPE on argparse not working

Tags: python, pipe, stdout, stdin, argparse

This is a snippet from a code written by my colleague. The code is for making a argument parser in python for some purpose.

```
if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    # Running in pipe mode
    pipe_mode = True
else:
    opts.add_argument('address', nargs='+')
```

What is happening is if we pipe stdin its not reading it. This is what I am trying to do:

```
subprocess.Popen(["nomadly-geocode", "-o", "json", values[1]],
                                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Since I am PIPE-ing stdout it should be working. But I am getting this error where it is not able to identify the arguments. ( The function works fine if we use command line to run it)

error:(lets say values[1] = Sydney)

```
usage: nomadly-cli-geocode [-h] [-o {parse,json,human}] [-u]
nomadly-cli-geocode: error: unrecognized arguments: Sydney
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't set stdin, the child process inherits stdin from its parent. If the parent's stdin is connected to a terminal then so is the stdin of the child process. Disable the child's stdin by setting it to `subprocess.NONE`.

Better yet, make address an optional argument. And check the value of the address argument rather what stdin is.

eg.

```
opt.add_argument("--address", "-a", nargs="*") 

... 

if not args.address:
    # try to get address from stdin
```